# ListActivity taking forever, application gives a blank screen

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listactivity

I am building an alarm application. A part of the application scans the internal and external memory of the device once a button is clicked, and then displays a `ListView` displaying all the audio files in the system. The relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
UpdateTime.java:

public class UpdateTime extends Activity {

    Intent changeSound;
    Button alarmSound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.update_time);

        alarmSound = (Button)findViewById(R.id.alarmSound);
        alarmSound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                changeSound = new Intent (UpdateTime.this, SelectAudio.class);
                startActivityForResult(changeSound, 1);         
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.update_time, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the class which finds the audio files and then displays them in `ListActivity`. I have checked the `listData()` method of this class somewhere else, and it is working just fine, so you can skip reading that part if you wish.

```
SelectAudio.class:

public class SelectAudio extends ListActivity {

    public static final int selectAudioInteger = 2;

    Intent incomingIntent;
    String fileName [];
    String fileTitle [];
    String names = "";
    String titles = "";

    ContentResolver myResolver;
    Cursor myCursor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myResolver = this.getContentResolver();
        incomingIntent = getIntent();
        listData();
        fileName = names.split("\n");
        fileTitle = titles.split("\n");

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, fileTitle));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String str =  fileName[position];
        incomingIntent.putExtra("fileTitle", str);
        setResult(selectAudioInteger, incomingIntent);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileTitle[position] + " selected" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        finish();
    }

    void listData()
    {
        Uri uriInternal = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri uriExternal = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor curExternal = myResolver.query(uriExternal, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, null, null);
        Cursor curInternal = myResolver.query(uriInternal, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, null, null);

        int iTitleExternal = curExternal.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int iTitleInternal = curInternal.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);

        int iNameExternal = curExternal.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        int iNameInternal = curExternal.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        while(!curExternal.moveToLast())
        {
            names = names + curExternal.getString(iNameExternal) + "\n";
            titles = titles + curExternal.getString(iTitleExternal) + "\n";
            curExternal.moveToNext();
        }

        while (!curInternal.moveToLast())
        {
            names = names + curInternal.getString(iNameInternal) + "\n";
            titles = titles + curInternal.getString(iTitleInternal) + "\n";
            curInternal.moveToLast();
        }

    }

}
```

The problem with this code is that once the button is clicked, the screen goes blank, and on logcat, I receive a message which reads like this:

```
03-19 18:18:18.798: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4a2a3d70 com.ikshvaku.intelligentalarm/.UpdateTime}
03-19 18:18:21.854: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.ikshvaku.intelligentalarm/.SelectAudio: 3053 ms (total 3053 ms)
03-19 18:18:28.322: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
03-19 18:18:28.855: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4a12ce98 com.ikshvaku.intelligentalarm/.SelectAudio}
```

I know, the solution of the problem is related with using AsyncTask class. I am just unable to find how to solve the problem.

Can anybody please help !!
Thanks.

Comment: problem is with `while(!curExternal.moveToLast())` what does it mean by you?

Comment: Since it's by a query, why not just use a CursorAdapter instead? There's plenty of examples out there for that.

Comment: @RajeshCP: I don't get your question ? Basically I checked this whole code on a separate ListActivity in a separate project. It worked there just fine there. When I imported the same code in this project, with some modifications, I was unable to get the desired result.

Comment: @Selvin: yeah, this part executes the loop unless the last row of the database has been searched. But I checked the whole listData() method somewhere else. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @RajeshCP: Well, the tutorial I learned from about LayoutActivity class used android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1 in setListAdapter method. That's where I have added the layout for ListActivity.

Comment: lol, no it is not ... it means `while(false)`(no loop at all) when cursor row count > 0 and `while(true)`(inf loop) if row count of cursor == 0 ... it makes no sens ...

Comment: @Selvin: Ok, but the loops works just fine. Both the cursor objects are moved to the next row in the corresponding loop(s)

Comment: no, they don't work fine ... if cursor have 0 rows then you have inf loop ...

Comment: @Selvin: yeah, that might be a problem. I'll rectify that piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

When your onCreate is called for the list activity... you should put a loading view and open a async task that goes and fetch your data... when the data is finally finished loading.. then update the list view... that way user knows your app is not frozen or anything... This is how I would've done it.. assuming rest of your code works perfectly!

```
public class SelectAudio extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myResolver = this.getContentResolver();
        incomingIntent = getIntent();
        fileName = names.split("\n");
        fileTitle = titles.split("\n");

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, fileTitle));
        new GetDataFromDisk().execute();
    }



    private class GetDataFromDisk extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             listData();
             return null;
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
            ArrayAdapter adapter = getListAdapter();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
    }
}
```